# Secure MySQL connection in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, security, jdbc, connection

I try this:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo","root","password");
```

but it's very easy for someone to hack strings of username and password.

> Opening Application with zip, winrar or any else program look like this and read code.

How can I secure my connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **decide** what permissions someone who gets a copy of your JAR has. Do they have permission to run database queries or not?

If they should not: delete the database connection. They don't have permission.

If they should: then they can have the password. They have permission.

What seems to be tripping you up is that you are giving out the **root** password for your database, and so you want the the third option: "They should be able to do some database queries, but not others."

*The JAR file is the wrong place to try to solve that problem.* If you try to solve this at the JAR file level, one of two things will happen. Either your users were trustworthy all along and you wasted your time with whatever elaborate scheme you used, or some of your end-users are untrustworthy and one of them will hack you. They will hack you by stepping it through the JVM and editing your query strings right before the JVM sends them out, at the very last second, if they absolutely have to. *Everything you do at this level will be security theater*, like getting frisked at the airport, it doesn't make you significantly safer but there is a tiny chance that you can say "but we *encrypted* it!" and your clients might not dump you after the inevitable security breach.

That problem needs to be solved *within the database*, by creating a user account which *does not have the permissions that they should not have*. When you do `SHOW GRANTS FOR enduser@'%'` it will show you only the sorts of queries that they are allowed to do.

In many cases you want to give the user account a more fine-grained permission than just INSERT, SELECT, or UPDATE on a table. For example, you might have the logic "you can add to this table, but only if you also update the numbers in this other table." For these, you should use stored procedures, which can have their permissions set to either "definer" or "invoker": define it by a user with the appropriate permissions and then the invoker gets to have advanced permissions to do this particular query.

In some cases you have a nasty situation where you want to distribute the same application to two different clients, but they would both benefit significantly (at the expense of the other!) from being able to read each other's data. For example you might be an order processor dealing with two rival companies; either one would love to see the order history of the other one. For these cases you have a few options:

1. Move even SELECT statements into stored procedures. A stored procedure can call `user()` which can still give you the logged-in user, even though they are not the definer.
2. Move the database queries out of the shared JAR. Like @g-lulu says above, you can create a web API which you lock down really well, or something like that.
3. Duplicate the database, move the authentication parameters to a separate file which you read on startup.

Option 3 requires you to write tooling to maintain multiple databases as perfect duplicates of each other's structure, which sucks. However it has the nice benefit over (1) and (2) that a shared database inevitably leaks *some* information -- for example an auto_increment ID column could leak how many orders are being created globally and there might be ways to determine something like, "oh, they send all of their orders through this unusual table access, so that will also bump this ID at the same time, so I just need to check to see if both IDs are bumped and that'll reveal an order for our rival company".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a webservice in PHP (or java or others). This webservice is stocked on a server and he's contain access and query to your database.
With your desktop app, just send a request (POST, GET) to your web service.
Exemple in PHP webservice :

```
if (isset($_POST['getMember'])){
do a query in your database
insert result into JSON
return JSON
}
```